# Why is the Content-Length HTTP header from not the same as on disk file size?

Tags: php, http, http-headers, filesystems

If I use PHP's `get_headers()` to return the Content-Length of an image file, why does this not match the size of the file if I save it to disk (OSX)?

```
protected function checkRemoteFile($url)
{
    $headers = get_headers($url,1);
    $size = $headers['Content-Length'];
    return $size;

}
```

Comment: How did you measure the size of saved file?

Comment: Try to post a minimal PHP example extracted from your code. There are a few possible explanations...

Answer (score 4):

Likely because the content was sent using Content-Encoding: gzip.